# Почему Google Apps ContentService выдает ошибку при преобразовании данных из таблицы?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

У меня есть таблица курсов валют

[image: table]

Я хочу их забирать в формате JSON через функцию [content service google apps script](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content).

Делаю то что указано в примере работает, а вот при получений данных из таблицы выдает ошибку

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null. (line 2, file "")

Вот мой код

[image: code0]

[image: code1]

Вот настройки публикации

[image: settings]

Comment: Не занимайтесь ерундой, вставьте код нормально. Ощущение, что вы на ссылках зарабатываете http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks getSheetByName null возникает тогда, когда вы не получили Таблицу. При вызове Таблицы, если она не найдена не генерируется исключение, а возвращается null.

Comment: Понял, спасибо! В след раз буду как вы оформлять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`getActiveSpreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=en#getActiveSpreadsheet()) не применим в данном случае, поскольку скрипт был вызван через HTTP запрос, а не из таблицы. Вместо него следует использовать [`openByUrl`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=en#openByUrl(String)) (или [`openById`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=en#openById(String))), указывая в виде параметра URL таблицы (или его часть).

Comment: Действительно, заработал с первого раза. Большое спасибо! Какой интересный момент однако )